# PHP connects to wrong host (Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'172.17.0.1' (using password: NO))

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

I am currently programing a little website, where the user can write and edit a database and I am busy trying to connect to my MySQL-Database by using Php.
The information of the Php-file then gets converted to JSON with the help of JavaScript. I am not using any libraries and use Xampp to create a local server environment.

Now when I try to connect to the Php-file, I get following message in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

When I look at the response of the Php-file I get following error message:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'172.17.0.1' (using password: NO) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Alben/data/interpret.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Alben/data/interpret.php(5): PDO-&gt;__construct('mysql:host=192....')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/Alben/data/interpret.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

I don't use the IP "172.17.0.1" and it doesn't appear anywhere in the code. I have no idea where that host comes from. I've looked up if anyone else had the same problem but I couldn't find anything similar from my quick search.

I believe that I have a problem with the backend. The JS-file I use to convert the Php-file doesn't appear to have any errors that might cause the problem. I will however add the JS-code too for the sake of clarity. I can also connect to my database inside my IDE (PhpStorm).

Here is the code of album.php:

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $host='192.168.100.55';
    private $port='8080';
    private $db_name='Alben';
    private $username='root';
    private $password='passwort';
    private $conn;

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->conn = null;
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO(
                'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';port=' . $this->port . ';dbname=' . $this->db_name,
                $this->username,
                $this->password
            );
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();
```

Here is the code of apps.js:

```
function ladeAlben() {
    fetch('data/album.php')
    .then((response) => {

        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            console.log("Request failed");
        }
    })
    .then((data) => {
        //HTML Erzeugen
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            html += '<tr><td>' + data[i].Alben_ID + '</td><td>' +
                data[i].Interpret + '</td><td>' + data[i].Name + '</td><td>' + data[i].Jahr + '</td><td>' + data[i].Medium + '</td><td>' + data[i].Genre + '</td><td>' +
                '</td><td>löschen</td><td>editieren</td>' + '</tr>';
        }

        var elem = document.getElementById("tableData");
        elem.innerHTML = HTML;
    })
}

ladeAlben();
```

If anyone here need more information concerning my problem, just ask me please.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `172.17.0.1` is the IP of the connecting server (your script), not the mysql server. Check the user/host permissions inside the database to make sure that user@172.17.0.1 is allowed to connect

Comment: Thank you for your reply, aynber. I will try this solution out tomorrow. I'll tell you afterwards if it worked or not.